# Why am I unable to copy to clipboard from vi editor?

Tags: centos, vi

I use old servers so I've to use vi editor. Problem is that I need to copy logs frequently and it's totally painful to do so. I've to convert that to a file, do SCP then only be able to get the logs. But companies that I serve for are reluctant to provide their logs and there's a huge procedure where I've to write email, get approved and what not just to share that logs to developer.

https://superuser.com/questions/227385/how-do-i-select-all-text-in-vi-vim

I saw this post and I was so happy that I now just need to create a new file and copy all of that and paste to clipboard. (I work via remote desktop software like anydesk).

But none of the mentioned commands there worked for my case.

ggVG didn't work. The top answer too didn't work. When I typed ggVG, it indeed showed "Visual Editor" but it didn't copy the selected text at all.

Is it practically possible to do so in vi editor?

I'm on centos 7.

We don't have root access to install anything on server plus since we have to monitor 100s of servers, it is very tough to manually install and configure stuffs in each servers.

Comment: `ggVG` doesn't actually do anything. It just selects text, but it doesn't tell Vim what to do with that selection. Pasting to the system clipboard will only work if (1) Vim has the clipboard feature enabled and (2) you have used X11 forwarding when connecting with ssh.

Comment: It's vi btw. Since it's minimal version X11 forwarding isn't enabled anywhere.

Comment: I don't think CentOS has vi packaged, not like Arch Linux has heirloom vi packaged. Like Ubuntu, vi is just Vim. Which particular build of Vim it is, depends. X11 forwarding isn't done by Vim, but by ssh.

Comment: At least inside a xfce4 terminal, if you select the text with the mouse, it's copied to the clipboard and you can copy by clicking the middle button. Not sure if that applies to your environment though.

Comment: Most of these settings require an X11-enabled vi. On CentOS 7 there's vim-x11 (not tested). On my Debian system there's vim-gtk3. With the GUI-enabled tool gvim which opens an additional window, but not the basic vim, I could get this link to behave as described: https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui_x11.html#x11-selection . If you don't have vim-x11 but only vim (vim-minimal, vim-enhanced ...) installed on CentOS chances are the feature won't be available. Now I also don't know the interaction with your remote tool similar to anydesk.

Comment: "But companies that I serve for are reluctant to provide their logs and there's a huge procedure where I've to write email, get approved and what not just to share that logs to developer.", and you're trying to get around this Company Policy? Are you trying to get fired (or jailed) and blacklisted? This seems unwise.